# Pycharm Pickle cant install

Tags: python, pycharm, pickle

so i cannot figure out how to install the pickle package to pycharm as i need it to call on other levels for my game i just cannot find the package on pycharm if anyone can help me or steer me to another thing like pycharm if anyone can help me with this it would be much appreciated i want to call on another level like you would call on a picture i have the right code for it just not the pickle package i have tried to research this problem but have not been able to get a solid answer so i turned to stack overflow as a last option

Comment: Are you sure? pickle module is a standard package in Python, so you should have it already installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if pickle present in pycharm or not by executing in cmd after entering into python in cmd.

```
help("modules")
```

[image]

check pickle module in it, If not try installing by

```
pip install pickle5
from pickle5 import pickle
```

If you still gets error please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Online tutorial videos for Python tell you need to install it, however, pickle is already a standard library in Python. You still have to type
`import pickle`
in the file.